# What happens if you do not listen to an audio message an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, messages

I do not want to open an audio message that was sent to me via iMessage. How do I get it to go away without deleting the whole conversation?

Sidenote… I do not have my read receipts on, so if I open the conversation but do not listen to the audio message, can i delete it without being noticed by the sender?

Comment: You'd delete it like any other message except don't touch the audio message, touch the previous message like you were going to delete it, however, when it gets selected to delete, uncheck it and then check the audio message, then touch the Trash can. 

If you have Send Read Receipts turned off, then they will never know.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 14.4.2, open Messages.app and scroll so the unwanted message appears. As an example, imagine the message "Fran and Bob are bringing flowers today" also includes an audio file (not shown in the attached screenshots):

[image]

Press **and hold** your finger on the message that contains the audio file; the audio file won't play. However, a contextual menu will appear:

[image]

Tap "More," and you'll see this:

[image]

The blue checkmark indicates the individual audio file (not the entire thread) has been selected. Touch the trash icon at the lower left, and the unwanted audio file will be deleted.

This action occurs only on your iPhone; the sender will not be notified that you have deleted the message or the file.